# Упростить jquery code

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте помогите упростить этот код , сократить строки ,записать в одно функцию...
благодарю за помощь :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hide-1").show();
    $("#hide-2").hide();
    $("#hide-3").hide();
    $("#hide-4").hide();
    $("#li-1").click(function () {
        $("#hide-1").show();
        $("#hide-2").hide();
        $("#hide-3").hide();
        $("#hide-4").hide();
    });
    $("#li-2").click(function () {
        $("#hide-2").show();
        $("#hide-1").hide();
        $("#hide-3").hide();
        $("#hide-4").hide();
    });
    $("#li-3").click(function () {
        $("#hide-3").show();
        $("#hide-2").hide();
        $("#hide-1").hide();
        $("#hide-4").hide();
    });
    $("#li-4").click(function () {
        $("#hide-4").show();
        $("#hide-2").hide();
        $("#hide-3").hide();
        $("#hide-1").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Разметку приведите. Классами все решается, но нужно знать как кнопки располагаются относительно блоков, которые необходимо прятать/показывать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут не код упрощать нужно, а подход к решению задачи менять. Вот набросал вам пример, он не идеальный, но даст пищу для размышления - http://jsfiddle.net/3wbnqv8m/

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

По вашему коду, можно поступить так, вдруг менять не будете...
1. Всем `#hide-1,#hide-2,#hide-N` назначить класс `hide-all`
2. Клик ловим на самом элементе или же общем классе

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hide-all").hide();
    $("#hide-1").show();
    /// id: #li-1,#li-2,....#li-N
    $("li").click(function (){
        var id = this.id.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,"");
        $(".hide-all").hide();
        $("#hide-"+id).show();
    });
});
```

Ну и лучше же прислушаться к @andreyqin