# Правка функции JQuery

Tags: jquery

Имеется вот такой вот код

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide").click(function(){
        $(".open_comment").fadeIn("slow");
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".open").click(function(){
        $(".open_comment").fadeOut("");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Разметка вот такая вот :

```
<div class="hide_comment">
     <a class="hide" href="#">посмотреть комментарий</a>
</div>
<div class="open_comment">
     <p>dfgdfgdfg</p>
     <a class="open" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Дело в том, что таких блоков 3. И при нажатии на ссылку .hide, открывается и остальных два блока, которые находятся ниже.
Подскажите как решить эту проблему, чтоб открывался только конкретные блок.

Comment: покажите разметку

Comment: <div class="hide_comment">
     <a class="hide" href="#">посмотреть комментарий</a>
</div>
 <div class="open_comment">
      <p>dfgdfgdfg</p>
      <a class="open" href="#"></a>
</div>

Comment: в сам вопрос ее добавляйте

Comment: вставьте один раз - я поправлю форматирование :-)

Comment: сдесь есть пример . илие попробуйте this [link](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413706/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-jquery-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что селектор `$(".open_comment")` выбирает **все** элементы на странице с этим классом.

А нужно просто выбрать нужный элемент, относительно текущего нажатого.

```
<div class="hide_comment"> 
    <a class="hide" href="#">посмотреть комментарий</a> 
</div> 
<div class="open_comment"> 
    <p>dfgdfgdfg</p> 
</div>
```

Для данной разметки:

нажатый элемент `<a class="hide"`, чтобы добраться до нужного `open_comment` нужно взять следующий элемент для родителя

внутри обработчика jQuery *this* указывает на нажатый элемента

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide").click(function(){

        $(this).parent() // родитель  class="hide_comment"
               .next() // следующий элемент  <div class="open_comment"> 
               .fadeIn("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

для *.open* аналогично, за исключением того, что родитель и будет нужным элементом.

Comment: Спасибо большое :)
заработало)

Answer (score 0):

Комментария нужно брать в отдельные div'ы. И при выборке применять `this`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.open_comment').fadeIn("slow");
        return false;
    });

    $(".open").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut("");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Разметка

```
<div>
    <div class="hide_comment">
         <a class="hide" href="#">посмотреть комментарий</a>
    </div>
    <div class="open_comment">
         <p>dfgdfgdfg</p>
         <a class="open" href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```